# remove agent from assembler queue part

Tags: anylogic

I have a problem with my code in Anylogic. I would like to remove/delete the agents in the assembler with a button. If the agents are in the delay part of the assembler I can remove them (that's where my code works). However, the agents that are in the queue contains part of the assembler are not deleted. I used the following code in my button's action field, but when I click the button, the stocks in the queue part of the assembler remain. Does anyone know a solution for this?

[Picture of my model in Anylogic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74j09.png)

My code to remove/delete the agents from the queue part of the assembler:

```
while(Lager_Oberteile.size() > 0) {
      Agent agent = Lager_Oberteile.removeFirst();
}
while(Lager_Plättchen.size() > 0) {
      Agent agent = Lager_Plättchen.removeFirst();
}

if (Klebestation.queueSize(1) > 0) {
     Agent agent = Klebestation.queueGet(1, 0);
     Klebestation.remove(agent);  
}    
if (Klebestation.queueSize(2) > 0) {
     Agent agent = Klebestation.queueGet(2, 0);
     Klebestation.remove(agent);       
} 

if (Klebestation.delaySize() == 1) {
     Agent agent = Klebestation.delayGet(0);
     Klebestation.remove(agent);
}

offene_Aufträge = 0;
Stopp1.unblock();
Stopp2.unblock();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove all agents in the queue using:

```
int numAgents = assembler.queue1.size();
for (int i=0; i<numAgents; i++) {
    assembler.queue1.remove(0);
}
```

You may be confused because the visual counter will not jump back to zero:
[image]

However, this only shows how many agents have entered that queue. You can always test such things with tracelns:

[image]

So use the code for all 5 queues and you are good.

Comment: Ah ok yes thats it, perfect thank you very much Benjamin.